# Create smooth sticky header transition with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I created a sticky header for my page:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  initNavbarScroll();
});

function initNavbarScroll() {
  const navbar = $("#navbar");
  const navbarTopOffset = navbar.offset().top;
  const stickedCls = "navbarSticked";

  $(window).scroll(() => {
    const isSticked = navbar.hasClass(stickedCls);
    const windowScrolledDown = $(window).scrollTop() > navbarTopOffset;

    if (windowScrolledDown) {
      if (!isSticked) {
        navbar.addClass(stickedCls);
      }
    } else {
      if (isSticked) {
        navbar.removeClass(stickedCls);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.navbarSticked {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

The header should be the same as on [this page](https://www.thenativeweb.io/).

As you can see in the code example above the transition of the header is not smooth it's a bit clunky.

How can I make it stick smoothly?

Comment: I use the chrome browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using css `position:sticky;` instead of `position:fixed`

https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/

Comment: awesome that's really helpful